# MySQL query not working using nested Select

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT messages.from AS `from`, messages.creation AS `creation`, account_images.profile AS `profile`, bio.user_full_name AS `user_full_name`
FROM messages
INNER JOIN account_images ON account_images.uuid=messages.from
INNER JOIN bio ON bio.uuid=messages.from
WHERE messages.to='{$user}'
ORDER BY `creation` DESC
)
GROUP BY `from`
```

Why this query not working? Is there something wrong with nested select statements? Please help me how to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

`FROM` is a mysql reserved keyword using from as column name should be in backtics otherwise you will get error `messages`.`from`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT messages.`from` AS `from`, messages.creation AS `creation`, account_images.profile AS `profile`, bio.user_full_name AS `user_full_name`
FROM messages
INNER JOIN account_images ON account_images.uuid=messages.`from`
INNER JOIN bio ON bio.uuid=messages.`from`
WHERE messages.to='{$user}'
ORDER BY `creation` DESC
)
GROUP BY `from`
```

[**Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: No it's working without nested select statement.. I want last result of messages that why I ma trying this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the unquoted `from` problem, the joins are in the wrong order.  You cannot refer to a table alias in an `on` clause before it is defined and you need a table alias on the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT messages.from AS `from`, messages.creation AS `creation`,
             account_images.profile AS `profile`, bio.user_full_name AS `user_full_name`
      FROM account_images INNER JOIN
           bio
           ON bio.uuid = messages.`from` INNER JOIN
           messages
           ON account_images.uuid = messages.`from`
      WHERE messages.to='{$user}'
      ORDER BY `creation` DESC
     ) t
GROUP BY `from`;
```

Finally, you are attempting to get the last message for a group using a technique explicitly described as unreliable in the MySQL documentation on `group by` extensions (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html)).